# How to add css to dynamic div Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply css to dynamic div id.

```
var status = var status = item.down().next().innerHtml();
if(status == "test")
{  
    var c = 'item_'+i ;
    c.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
    //'item'+ i.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
}
```

here "item_" + i is a dynamic Ids of every rows.like item_1,item_2,item_3 etc. So I want to add css in some of the rows. ie . item_1 and item_3 or else.

So how can this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply the style property to string instead you need to get the element by `id`. Use **[`documet.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** for that

```
var status = var status = item.down().next().innerHtml();
if(status == "test")
{  
    var c = 'item_'+i ;
    document.getElementById(c).style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
    //'item'+ i.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
}
```

Or use jQuery **[id-selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)** and for applying css use **[`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/)**

```
var status = var status = item.down().next().innerHtml();
if(status == "test")
{  
    var c = 'item_'+i ;
    $('#'+c).css('background-color','rgb(255, 125, 115)');
    //'item'+ i.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add  CSS to dynamic div you can use the following syntax

```
$("div"+dynamic_id).css({"color":"rgb(255, 125, 115)"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as mentioned other users, or you can also use the below,
basically if you use pure JavaScript then you have to identify the element first by using the function `document.getElementbyId`

```
var c = document.getElementbyId('item_' + i);
c.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 125, 115)';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for achieving result you want.In addition to others answers you can also do like this with jquery

```
$("div#"+dynamic_id).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 125, 115)");
```